# episerver preview loads over http instead of https when changing language

Tags: episerver, mixed-content, episerver-6

i have a website "https://example.com", with episerver 6 cms.

When i go into the backend, the english page shows perfectly well, no issues there. I can see the preview of the page and everything.

Then i try to change to the danish site, and it changes fine, but now the preview doesn't work.

in the console it says the preview was loaded over http, and not https, and therefore sends a mixed content warning, and blocks the preview.

How do i get it to show the preview ?

how do i make it so changing the language of the page, doesn't load over http ?

**Edit**
I have tried adding https or :443 to the urls in episerverframework.config, which only resulted in the site crashing.

Comment: admin -> config -> manage web sites -> click site -> play with scheme field, most probably should be empty or HTTPS

Comment: scheme field ? meaning host name or URL? i tried putting https on URL in general, but it did not work.

Comment: And your IIS is setup to handle the danish hostname over https?

Comment: @EricHerlitz yep.. I have multiple other sites on this very solution, with no issues.